"Randomly" long wait for Memory Grant despite low memory usage
I have a stored procedure that most of the time runs in ~172ms.
If I run keep running it, then every so often, it takes ~10 seconds.
Diagnosing the query plans, despite the same strategy being produced in both cases, it will have a warning:

The query had to wait 10 seconds for MemoryGrant during execution

This is despite the MemoryGrant section showing it was requesting just 21MB of memory. This is an otherwise idle server so memory pressure generally isn't an issue.
It's requesting similar amounts in the other queries when there is 0 wait time on the grant.
Why does SQL server appear to sometimes take an astronomical time to grant a relatively small amount of memory, and is there anything that can be done about this?
